# Use mean value theorem to prove $ \lim_{x \to \infty}\left( f(x+1)-f(x) \right)=a ~$ as $ ~\lim_{ x \to \infty}f'(x)=a $

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

$$ f(x) :=\text{continuous and 1st order differentiable function} $$

$$ \lim_{ x \to \infty}f'(x)=a $$

What I want to prove is the below statement.

$$ \lim_{ x \to \infty}\left( f(x+1)-f(x) \right) =a  $$

I guess that using mean value theorem is the key to deduce it however I've been stuck from here.

Can anyone give me some hint(s)? so that I can deduce it in my own.

Comment: You are right: use the mean value theorem on the segment $[x,x+1]$.

Comment: Not very rigorous, but notice that wrt x, 1 is infinitesimally small, which  means that the statement to be proved is just a variation of the definition of the derivative.

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta Why does your argument not work for $f(x)=\sin x$?

Comment: @Gae.S. because $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\cos(x)$ does not exist

Comment: $f(x)$ is approximately linear with slope $a$ as $x\to \infty$, so $f(x+1) \approx f(x) + a$.

Comment: @CSquared I know that the person who made the exercise up knows that you need additional hypothesis. Fortunately he was there, otherwise we'd all be chasing a wild goose.